# What is -lutil means in g++ complie option?

Tags: c++, g++

What is the purpose of **-lutil** option in g++ compile options? I Google this, but doesn't find good explains.

Better explain with an short example.

Comment: Is it `-lutil` or `-util`?

Comment: `-lutil` means link with the util library.

Comment: @john Not in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-lutil` is a use of the `-l<library>` link option. To will instruct the linker to search for, and possibility link against, a library named libutil.

libutil is part of glibc and contains some BSD derived functions:

- [openpty/forkpty/login_tty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/forkpty.3.html)
- [logwtmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/updwtmp.3.html)
- [login/logout](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/login.3.html)

These functions are not part of any C, C++, or POSIX standard. login, logout, and logwtmp are used to manage the utmp/wtmp login accounting files. openpty, forkpty, and login_tty are part of the deprecated BSD pty implementation.